# Turn a distances squareform to long format in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, distance

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

ids = ['1', '2', '3']
points=[(0,0), (1,1), (3,3)]
distances = pdist(np.array(points), metric='euclidean')
print(distances)
distance_matrix = squareform(distances)
print(distance_matrix)
```

prints:

```
[1.41421356 4.24264069 2.82842712]
[[0.         1.41421356 4.24264069]
 [1.41421356 0.         2.82842712]
 [4.24264069 2.82842712 0.        ]]
```

as expected

I want to turn this into a long format for writing in csv, as in

```
id1,id2,distance
1,1,0
1,2,1.41421356
1,3,4.24264069
2,1,1.41421356
2,2,0
2,3,2.82842712
```

etc - how should I go about it for maximum efficiency? Using pandas is an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DataFrame` contructor with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix, index=ids, columns=ids).stack().reset_index()
df.columns=['id1','id2','distance']
print (df)
  id1 id2  distance
0   1   1  0.000000
1   1   2  1.414214
2   1   3  4.242641
3   2   1  1.414214
4   2   2  0.000000
5   2   3  2.828427
6   3   1  4.242641
7   3   2  2.828427
8   3   3  0.000000
```

Or `DataFrame` contructor with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1':np.repeat(ids, len(ids)), 
                   'id2':np.tile(ids, len(ids)),
                   'dist':distance_matrix.ravel()})
print (df)
  id1 id2      dist
0   1   1  0.000000
1   1   2  1.414214
2   1   3  4.242641
3   2   1  1.414214
4   2   2  0.000000
5   2   3  2.828427
6   3   1  4.242641
7   3   2  2.828427
8   3   3  0.000000
```

Comment: Thanks - those index operations still escape me. Do you think I could somehow avoid the squareform (thought to be slow in general). The matrices have many elements.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D - Do you think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34418376) solution?

Comment: Will have a look - there is also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35413316/281545 - but your solution will do for now - I need to time to see if I need to optimize :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`indices_merged_arr_generic_using_cp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46135435/) -

Helper function -

```
import numpy as np
import functools

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/46135435/ by @unutbu
def indices_merged_arr_generic_using_cp(arr):
    """
    Based on cartesian_product
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645/190597 (senderle)
    """
    shape = arr.shape
    arrays = [np.arange(s, dtype='int') for s in shape]
    broadcastable = np.ix_(*arrays)
    broadcasted = np.broadcast_arrays(*broadcastable)
    rows, cols = functools.reduce(np.multiply, broadcasted[0].shape), len(broadcasted)+1
    out = np.empty(rows * cols, dtype=arr.dtype)
    start, end = 0, rows
    for a in broadcasted:
        out[start:end] = a.reshape(-1)
        start, end = end, end + rows
    out[start:] = arr.flatten()
    return out.reshape(cols, rows).T
```

Usage -

```
In [169]: out = indices_merged_arr_generic_using_cp(distance_matrix)

In [170]: np.savetxt('out.txt', out, fmt="%i,%i,%f")

In [171]: !cat out.txt
0,0,0.000000
0,1,1.414214
0,2,4.242641
1,0,1.414214
1,1,0.000000
1,2,2.828427
2,0,4.242641
2,1,2.828427
2,2,0.000000
```

To get `distance_matrix` we can also use `Scipy's cdist` : `cdist(points, points)`. There's also [`eucl_dist`](https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist)  package  (disclaimer: I am its author) that contains various methods to compute euclidean distances that are much more efficient than `SciPy's cdist`, especially for large arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - do you think it will be faster ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Think you need to test it out. Also, consider the alternatives listed in the edits at the end of the post.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D So, did you try it out? Any feedback?

Comment: Not yet and it may take a while I am in the middle of a project - will do eventually